# Android: Parsing JSON arrays

Tags: arrays, json, android-recyclerview

My application parses JSON data and displays it in an recycler view. If the user selects an item from the recycler view, more information is displayed in a different activity. The JSON response contains three JSON arrays that I want to get data from. The Offices, Officials, and Address arrays. The application works fine for some pieces of data, but when I try to parse data from the address array, I get an error from the logcat that says "JSONException: No value for address." If I comment out the code that retrieves address data, the code app runs. Here is a snippet of the JSON response

```
  {
 "normalizedInput": {
  "line1": "2613 Irvington Avenue",
  "city": "San Bernardino",
  "state": "CA",
  "zip": "92407"
 },
 "offices": [
  {
   "name": "President of the United States",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "headOfState",
    "headOfGovernment"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Vice-President of the United States",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "United States Senate",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorUpperBody"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "United States House of Representatives CA-31",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorLowerBody"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Governor",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "headOfGovernment"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Lieutenant Governor",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "City Treasurer"
  },
  {
   "name": "Mayor"
  },
  {
   "name": "City Attorney"
  },
  {
   "name": "City Clerk"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sheriff-Coroner"
  },
  {
   "name": "Auditor-Controller-Treasurer-Tax Collector"
  },
  {
   "name": "District Attorney"
  },
  {
   "name": "Assessor-Clerk-Recorder"
  },
  {
   "name": "San Bernardino County Superior Court Judge"
  },
  {
   "name": "CA State Assembly District 40"
  },
  {
   "name": "CA State Senate District 23"
  },
  {
   "name": "Board of Supervisors, District 5"
  },
  {
   "name": "Secretary of State"
  },
  {
   "name": "State Treasurer"
  },
  {
   "name": "Attorney General"
  },
  {
   "name": "State Superintendent of Public Instruction"
  },
  {
   "name": "State Controller"
  },
  {
   "name": "Insurance Commissioner"
  }
 ],
 "officials": [
  {
   "name": "Donald J. Trump",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "The White House",
     "line2": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20500"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 456-1111"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/whitehouse.gov/files/images/45/PE%20Color.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "potus"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    }
   ]
  },
```

Here is the method that handles the JSON parsing.

```
//fetch json data from Civic API
    private void getData(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    //first loop through offices array. Retrieve officeName value
                    JSONArray officesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("offices");        //One array for offices
                    JSONArray officialsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("officials");    //one array for officials
                    //JSONArray addressArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("address");        //one array for address
                    for (int i = 0; i < officesArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonOffices = officesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsonOfficials = officialsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //JSONObject jsonAddress = addressArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (jsonOfficials.has("photoUrl")) {
                            Reps reps1 = new Reps(jsonOffices.getString("name"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("name"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("party"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("photoUrl"));
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("line1"),
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("city"),
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("state"),
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("zip"),
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("phones")
                            //);

                            repList.add(reps1);
                        } else {
                            Reps reps2 = new Reps(jsonOffices.getString("name"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("name"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("party"));
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("line1"),
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("city"),
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("state"),
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("zip"),
                                    //jsonAddress.getString("phones")
                           //);

                            repList.add(reps2);
                        }
                    }
                    adapter = new RepRvAdapter(repList, getApplicationContext());
                    myrv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

I commented out the lines that parse the address data and the app works. The moment I uncomment those lines, a blank activity is shown and the logcat error displays. Here is a picture of the logcat

[image]
I think the issue is because the Address array is nested in the Officials array. Do I have to traverse the Officials Array to get the address data? If so, How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: "address" is not a top level property of your object. It is a member of an object in the  "officials" array.

Comment: You need to traverse the "officials" array and get the "address" out of each "official" object.